# WP7: can't get img from httpget url using webclient.OpenReadAsync

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, webclient, http-get

I need to get image from this API on Windows phone7 appplication,

**getvmsimg**

Description :

```
API for get variable message sign (VMS) as img
```

URL:

```
http://athena.traffy.in.th/apis/apitraffy.php?api=…&id=…[w=...]&[h=...]
```

Formats:

```
Image: PNG
```

HTTP Method:

```
GET
```

Requires Authentication :

```
true
```

API rate limited :

```
unlimited
```

---

and this is my code 
I have to get a session key by another API first(Completely,No problem) and then i have to use the session key as a parameter in httpget url.
my key is correctly 100 percent, i have checked.
but It error at **"image.SetSource(e.Result);" line** (Unspecified error).

```
public intsign()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.traffy.in.th/apis/getKey.php?appid="+appid));

}

void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    rd = e.Result;
    sessionkey = MD5Core.GetHashString(appid + rd) + MD5Core.GetHashString(hiddenkey + rd);
    //MessageBox.Show(sessionkey);

    client2.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client2_OpenReadCompleted);
    client2.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://athena.traffy.in.th/apis/apitraffy.php?api=getvmsimg&key=" + sessionkey + "&appid=" + appid + "&id=1&h=480&w=480"),client2);
}

void client2_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.SetSource(e.Result);
    intsignimg.Source = image;
}
```

thx, guy

Comment: You visit the second url in a browser and it succeeds?

Comment: yes, it display img(.png) successfully.

Comment: Time to dig out the Fiddler tool, examine the successful HTTP conversation your browser has when using that URL and compare it with the conversation your Silverlight app has trying to retreive the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to write the **entire stream** (with a buffer or else) into a **MemoryStream** and then use that MemoryStream instead of using directly the resulting stream ?